# Django model field values returning blank?

Tags: python, django, windows, django-models

I have a model named "Person" with two character fields - first_name and last_name. I have migrated them using makemigrations in the shell and have set the value of first_name to my first name. However, whenever I try to set a value for last_name it returns blank. For example:

```
 a = Person(last_name="...")
 a.save()
 a.id
 id=...
 Person.objects.get(id=...)
 <Person: >
```

The value will just be blank in the brackets. Here is my models.py if it's relevant:

```
 from django.db import models

 class Person(models.Model):
      first_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
      last_name = models.CharField(max_length=6)

      def __str__(self):
         return self.first_name
```

I'm not entering a value that is beyond the max_length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__str__` only returns the `self.first_name` hence it means that it will *print* the `Person` as `<Person: last_name>` with *`last_name`* the `last_name` of the `Person`.

If you thus rewrite this to:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=6)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'
```

it will *print* the person object with its first and last name.

But saving it in the database, and retrieving it works, regardless of the implementation of `__str__`.

If you for example obtain the `.last_name` attribute, it will print:

```
>>> Person.objects.get(id=some_id).last_name
'...'
```